# How can I add enhanced tooltip content to heatmap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have added a 4th term into the json heatmap data which doesn't break the heatmap, but how do I address the new 4th term  in the tooltip formatter below?

Original implicit [x, y, z] 3 term array
{"name":"zaxis","data":[[0,488,3],[0,488,3],...

new enhanced [x, y, z, comment] 4 term array
{"name":"zaxis","data":[[0,488,3,"-90.8 | -87.5 | 0.0 | 0.0"],[0,488,3,"-103.4 | -99.4 | 0.0 | 0.0"],...

```
formatter: function () {
return '<b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y]+ '</b>' +
'<br><b>' + this.point.value + '</b> dB' + 
' at <b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b>';
},
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer was posted on the highcharts support board> 
 I should have looked there a bit more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use [`keys`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cheatmap%3E.keys), so you could have a smaller JSON data to send.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ysyse7w5/1/

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: [
      [0, 0, 10, 'custom text 1'],
      [0, 1, 100, 'custom text 2'],
      [1, 0, 100, 'custom text 3'],
      [1, 1, 10, 'custom text 4']
    ],
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'value', 'text'],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter() {
        return this.y + '<br>' + this.point.text
      }
    }
  }]
```